# Rails 3, how to setup has_many form and Controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many

I have these Models

```
class User #( Devise)
  has_many :codes 
  has_many :redemptions
end

class Code
  belongs_to :band
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :redemptions
end

class Redemption
  has_one :code
  belongs_to :user
end

class Band
  has_many :codes
end
```

I am trying to do most of the work in the `Band#show` view.  So I have a band_controller action `redeem`.

My goal is that the `current_user` (provided by devise) inputs a code into a form input (created by another user) and submits to the `Band#redeem` action and puts the `user_id` and `code_id` into a redeem object. This creates a redemption.

The crazy piece of this is that one user creates a code, another redeems it.  I have the Redemption model built.

```
<%= form_for @band, :url => {:action => "redeem"}, do |f|  %>
  <%#= f.text_field  :code  %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

It's the current form I have setup.  This obviously doesn't work but it's what I am trying to wire up.

Comment: Strongly suggest you check out simple_form - https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form every top rails developer I know uses it (it's also got 1500 forks, i.e. heavily used...).  Given the models you have and the probable current and future functionality.  I lost hair until I found simple_form (built on formtastic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a `redeem`-action on `BandsController`, I suggest you simply use `RedemptionsController#create`. Something like the following:

```
class BandsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @band       = Band.find(params[:id])
    @redemption = Redemption.new(code: @band.codes.first)
  end
end

# in bands/show template
<%= form_for @redemption do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :code_id %>
  <%= f.submit "Redeem now" %>
<% end %>
```

This form will `POST`to `RedemptionsController#create` where you simply create the redemption.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I also have to pass the current_user.id to the new action.  can I do that in the controller action? something like: @redemption = Redemption.new(params[:redemption], :user_id => current_user.id)

Comment: In `RedemptionsController#create` you can use `current_user`, which is provided by Devise, like this: `@redemption = current_user.redemptions.new(params[:redemption])`.